# Definition of Smooth Representation

Tags: representation-theory

For simplicity, let's say $G=GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. The compact open subgroups are $K_i=\{g\in G: g\equiv 1\pmod{p^i}\}$.

We say a homomorphism $\rho: G\to GL(V)$ is a smooth representation if for every vector $v\in V$ ($V$ is a complex vector space), there is a compact open subgroup of $G$ that stablizes $v$.

My question is how is the word "smooth" appropriate for this context? $G$ doesn't have the structure of a smooth (real or complex) manifold so what exactly does it mean for this map to be smooth? I am assuming we endow $GL(V)$ with the analytic topology. However, $V$ is very often infinite dimensional so what topology do we endow it with?

Addendum: In the usual definition of smooth representations or continuous representations, we don't have a particular restriction on the complex vector space $V$. That is we don't require them to be Hilbert spaces, Banach spaces or have any other "nice" topological/analytic structure. So we can endow a discrete topology on $V$ but then we can't put any meaningful topology on $GL(V)$, either.

Comment: Here is an interesting discussion on this : https://math.ou.edu/~kmartin/autreps/ch2.pdf 
At part 2.3 the author describes why smooth representation are called like this although he admits that the definition for $GL(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is not very intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for the link @AlexandreSallinen! These notes do attempt to motivate some of the definition which is taken for granted often. However, there are still some pending questions. 2.3.2 implies that f is still continuous even if V has the discrete topology on  it. Why would we choose the discrete topology, though?

Comment: I guess that $2.3.2$ gives us a feeling of how much  smoothness is stronger than continuity as no matter the topology you will apply on $V$, a smooth representation will be continuous. Essentially it tells you that "smoothness is as good as being continuous on every possible topology"